500 A DC from shunt to battery bus bar, how do you carry the power?
System is nominally 12 V DC but it is connected to LiFePO4 batteries so the charging voltage is 14.4 V DC. There is currently 900 AH of battery capacity, soon to be 1200 AH.
Load side is 2 inverters 2000 W (existing: ~166 A DC), and 3000 W (new: ~250 A DC) plus various DC loads (mostly insignificant and those that aren't have a short duty cycle: winches, windlass).
I have a battery bus bar rated at 600 A DC. I'm thinking to run a completely separate set of wires from to the new inverter because that much current is just too much for 4/0 Marine Cables.
Problem is, I need to run everything back through a single shunt to measure the power being used and give me some idea of how much juice is still in the batteries. So I'm thinking to run two 4/0 cables from shunt to busbar. I don't like this because a loose connection on either wire ends up running all the current through one of the wires.  But, outside of building a solid copper bar to get from point A to point B, I don't know how else to do it. The length of the wires from busbar to shunt will be under 12 inches, just enough to make the transition from one piece to the other.
If I was building a new boat, I'd go 24 V DC or 48 V DC to keep the amperage down but replacing all those expensive boat things isn't worth it. $5000 for new windlass and winch motors is just laughable.

Thicker cable with terminations is available in the current rating you need. Is there a reason you can't use that?

I'd be tempted to use the cables busbar to each inverter as shunts. OTOH, the inverters may offer measurements and statistics.

@AndrewMorton I'm not sure what you are referring to.  I know of no 4/0 marine cabling that can handle 500ADC. (batteries are capable of delivering more than 500ADC but outside of a short all the systems on the boat can't ask for that much power and not like I can find a larger shunt.

@greybeard The Victron shunt in question is BT enabled and will log via their CerboGX system.   One inverter is Victron and might offer some instrumentation but since the power flowing to/from the inverter might not be going thru the batteries.  I have 3KW of solar that will supply power for most of the day and can even charge the batteries while the AC runs.  So I can't use the inverters for any time of record keeping.

@boatcoder Why are you limited to 4/0 cables? Is there no possibility of using cables with more current capacity?

Rather than trying to run all of your current through a bussbar and shunt, which in a marine application is going to be difficult to keep corrosion free, why not use hall effect sensors on your output lines? Hall Effect sensors are used in automotive electrical systems and work under the same principal as Clamp on Ampmeters. They are robust and just need to encircle your cabling.
If you have an ICE that uses a variable current alternator, you'll find a Hall Sensor on the Negative cable between the battery and frame.

Upvoted for taking slim hints on application.

This is the most interesting of all the solutions.  If I did this and connected it to a BT, maybe I could get the info into SignalK.  That's at least a thought.  Thanks.
